# CoffeeScript makes a global variable of `v` in `for v in values` causing wrong references at events

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, happening

I have the following CoffeeScript code:

```
for date of dates
    Dom.section !->
        Dom.div !->
            Dom.text if date.attending then 'Y' else 'N'
            Dom.onTap !->
                Dom.text date.id
```

Which is converted to the following JavaScript (according to coffeescript.org)

```
var date;

for (date in dates) {
  Dom.section(!function() {
    return Dom.div(!function() {
      Dom.text(date.attending ? 'Y' : 'N');
      return Dom.onTap(!function() {
        return Dom.text(date.id);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Do not bother what the code does exactly since I am making use of the API of Happening (a new conversation app for which uses can make plugins, in CoffeeScript) and because of that, you wouldn't understand it anyway.

I will explain it though:

- `dates` is an array of length 10 with objects in it. These objects contain keys like `id`, `day`, `year`, `attending`.
- I loop over all the dates and render these in so called 'sections' on the screen.
- Every section contains several divs (in the example above there is only one, for the sake of simplicity).
- The div above contains some text. 'Y' when the user is attending the event, 'N' when he is not.
- When the user taps ('onTap'-event) on this div, it will update the local and shared storage (in the example above it will just add some text for debugging).

Everything is working, it shows the correct date and amount of attendees in the correct sections. So the `date`-object contains the correct data.

## The problem

The problem I am having is when I tap on the div with the onTap-event. When I tap it, it will always use the last date which is rendered. So let's say I have the dates `01-12-14` to `10-12-14`. I tap on `05-12-14`, it will add the id of 10-12-14 as text on the screen. After some long headbreaking and cursing I found what is causing this, but I don't know how to solve it.

See the first line of the JavaScript (seconde code example). As you can see it is declaring a global variable `date`. Everything renders fine, but when I click on something, it will refer to `date`, but since `date` has been updated on the last iteration of the loop, it will always use that id.

So. How can I make sure that `date` keeps private per iteration loop and make sure it uses the correct value at an event?

## Note

`for k, v in dates` isn't working either, since it makes `k` global as well. So simply using `dates[k].id` won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not declaring a *global*, just something global to that code. If it were within a function, it wouldn't be a global.

The problem has nothing to do with globals. It's because of how closures work. Closures have an *enduring reference* to the variables they close over, not a *copy* of their value as of when the closure was created. So all of the functions you're creating for your `onTap` handlers use the same, single `date` object.

To prevent that, give them each something of their own to close over that doesn't change. If `dates` is an array, use `forEach`.

(Note to those familiar with CoffeeScript but not Happening: The `!` in front of the `->` isn't the usual `!` operator. Happening extends CoffeeScript such that a function is declared using `!->` instead of `->`, the implicit return value Coffeescript normally has is not generated. *[With thanks to [Erik Dolor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583447/erik-dolor) for pointing that out.]*)

So:

```
dates.forEach (date) !->
    Dom.section !->
        Dom.div !->
            Dom.text if date.attending then 'Y' else 'N'
            Dom.onTap !->
                Dom.text date.id
```

...which becomes this JavaScript:

```
dates.forEach(function(date) {
  Dom.section(function() {
    Dom.div(function() {
      Dom.text(date.attending ? 'Y' : 'N');
      Dom.onTap(function() {
        Dom.text(date.id);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Now, the closure created for each iteration of the `forEach` callback closes over the *argument* `date` for that callback iteration, which doesn't change.